# SQL result as txt.file by php

Tags: php, mysql, text, output, fopen

I have a php file, which transform my sql query in a php output. Everything works fine. But now i need a output as txt.file and my code does not work.

Here the query:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB', 'USER', 'PW');

$result = ("SELECT o.order_id AS Bestellnummer, o.customer_id AS Kundennummer, o.order_status_id AS Bestellstatus, op.quantity AS Anzahl, op.model AS Pharmacode, op.name AS Bezeichnung, p.location AS Lieferant, o.shipping_company AS Firma, o.shipping_firstname AS Vorname, o.shipping_lastname AS Nachname, o.shipping_address_1 AS Lieferadresse, o.shipping_postcode AS PLZ, o.shipping_city AS Ort
FROM oc_order o
INNER JOIN oc_order_product op
ON o.order_id = op.order_id
INNER JOIN oc_product p
ON op.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE o.order_status_id = 1 AND p.location = 1
ORDER BY o.order_id, op.model");



echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Best.Nr</th>
<th>Kd.Nr</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Anz.</th>
<th>Pharmacode</th>
<th>Bezeichnung</th>
<th>Lieferant</th>
<th>Firma</th>
<th>Vorname</th>
<th>Nachname</th>
<th>Adresse</th>
<th>PLZ</th>
<th>Ort</th>
</tr>";

foreach ($pdo->query($result) as $row) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Bestellnummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Kundennummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Bestellstatus'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Anzahl'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Pharmacode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Bezeichnung'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Lieferant'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Firma'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Vorname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Nachname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Adresse'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['PLZ'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Ort'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I need the endcode for a output in txt or csv. I suppose that the initial code (SELECT...) has no clear output string to connect at a new code for the output.

Comment: The last code is correct, the only difference is using `mysql_*` functions instead of `PDO`, which will pose a problem in PHP 7.

Comment: `mysql` extension is deprecated. Start using `mysqli` or `PDO` to save yourself from vulnerability attacks like `SQL Injection` and like that.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil `mysql` extension does not only pose a problem in PHP 7. It is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0. Versions after 5.5.0 will all pose problems using `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try collect full string by PHP and than put it to file:
So you need create `$string` variable before loop and append each row to `$string`:

```
$string = "";
$file_path = "file.csv";
foreach ($pdo->query($result) as $row) {
  $string .= $row['Bestellnummer'] . ',';
  ...
}
file_put_contents($file_path, $string)
```

Comment: I tried but without positive effect :file_put_contents("test.txt", $output); needs $query = $this->db->$query("output"); and this does not work with my primary code.

Comment: Show your code, please

Comment: hi, it was not possible to answer with the entire code, so I've posted the entire code in the initial question.